# Write a mutate function using lambda

Tags: python, lambda

I need to write a function that called "mutate to" compute all words generated by a single mutation on a given word.
A mutation is defined as inserting a character, deleting a character, replacing a character, or swapping 2 consecutive characters in a string. For simplicity consider only letters froma to z

For example:

```
words = mutate("hello")
'helo' in words
True
'cello' in words
True
'helol' in words
True
```

This is the code that I managed to do until now:

```
letters = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','m','l','n','o','p','q','r','s','t' ,'u','v','w','x','y','z']
mutate = lambda x: [''.join([x[:i], l, x[i+1:len(x)]])
                    for i in range(len(x)) 
                    for l in letters]
```

How can I also put in one line, deleting a character, and swapping 2 consecutive characters in a string?

Comment: Why the one line requirement? This would read much better if it was on multiple lines, one for each case

Comment: i would define that to be an object to save some memory. your requirement can make your ram explode if you try to enumerate all possibilities.

Comment: The exercise concentrates on the functionality of the lambda
That the demand is to do everything in one line within the lambda function

Comment: More readable: `from string import ascii_lowercase`, `letters = list(ascii_lowercase)`

Comment: could you provide a link? fp doesn't mean oneliners from the top to the bottom.

Comment: The exercise is written in Hebrew, but I'm sure that the demand is to put everything into one line otherwise the exercise is not difficult at all ...
Ps Thank Alexander I changed the code

Comment: @H_meir: somehow I doubt the assignment is to put everything in one line. That in itself is not a challenge but perhaps correctly using lambda is. Are you sure the assignment specifies to write everything as a one-liner?

Answer (score 1):

Does this count as use of `lambda`?

```
import string

def f1(word):
    return set(word[:i] + c + word[i:] for i in range(len(word) + 1) for c in string.ascii_lowercase)

def f2(word):
    return set((word[:i] + word[i + 1:]) for i in range(len(word)))

def f3(word):
    return set((word[:i] + c + word[i + 1:] for i in range(len(word)) for c in string.ascii_lowercase))

def f4(word):
    return set((word[:i] + word[i + 1] + word[i] + word[i + 2:]) for i in range(len(word) - 1))

mutate = lambda word: set(f1(word) | f2(word) | f3(word) | f4(word))
```

This defines a function for each of the four cases and then defines `mutate` as the set of all possible words generated by those cases.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but unfortunately not

Comment: I don't thing there is any difficulty in one-lining this, although it is one big line

Comment: How can I put in this one line? (Even if large)

Comment: trivially : `mutate = lambda word: set(word[:i] + c + word[i:] for i in range(len(word) + 1) for c in string.ascii_lowercase).union(set((word[:i] + word[i + 1:]) for i in range(len(word)))).union(set((word[:i] + c + word[i + 1:] for i in range(len(word)) for c in string.ascii_lowercase))).union(set((word[:i] + word[i + 1] + word[i] + word[i + 2:]) for i in range(len(word) - 1)))`